# Python xml.etree.ElementTree issue, Element.tag is getting me more than just the tag name

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having a lot of trouble doing something as simple as just getting the tag of an Element from an XML file. This is the element, with sensitive info removed:

```
<FIXML xmlns="AAA/AAAAA-5-0-AAA" v="AAA.5.AAAA" xv="111" cv="AAA" s="2013-10-14">
```

I attempted to get the tag of this element with this simple line of code:

```
tag1 = root.tag
```

And for some reason this is not behaving as expected. It is giving me this value:

```
{AAA/AAAAA-5-0-AAA}FIXML
```

It's attaching the value of the first attribute to it, as a prefix in curly braces? Why on earth is it doing that? I just want it to return FIXML and nothing else, which according to the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is what I understood it to do. Any ideas?

Python version: 3.7

Comment: The value enclosed in curly braces is the namespace. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User mzjn was correct here, I didn't realize that namespaces were returned as well. The way I resolved this was by stripping the namespace off:

```
# Strip namespace off of root tag
if '}' in tag:
    tag = tag.split('}', 1)[1]
```

This resulted in the intended output by stripping everything after the closing tag. Obviously this assumes there's no } character in the tag or namespace itself.

Comment: I know you accepted your answer and it does work in this case; but generally it's not a good idea to deal with xml in this manner. In the long run, you'd probably be better off parsing the xml with an xml parser (like lxml) and using standard methods to deal with the namespace.

Comment: This was a long time ago but yes I agree. Literally the only reason I was doing this was because we had an old process that needed the CSV file in a very specific format. Otherwise I never would have bothered.